# Fetch file last one minute ago from the current time using nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Im throwing multiple `csv` files on my `hdfs` every minute using `logstash`.

I need to get the files from the past minute from the current time.

Im using `nifi` in this process.

For example right now is 11:30 AM, I need to get ONLY all the files that are saved 1 minute ago or 11:29AM.

What is the best approach here using `nifi`?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your files put in hdfs appends with time or not?

Comment: im naming my hdfs files like this file-08-23-17-11-29-AM.
Is there a better way?

Comment: yes that is better way to fetch file based on time present in your filename

Comment: how will i do that? Need to get last 1 min ago.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check following flow structure.

**ListHDFS-->RouteOnAttribute-->FetchHDFS**

You can use ListHDFS it lists all files from hdfs folder.

Use RouteOnAttribute to check datetime present in filename is previous minute or not by convert **'08-23-17-11-29-AM'** into **milliseconds(toNumber())** .

Then check it to be equal to that milliseconds with previous minutes of current datetime like below.
**${now():toNumber():minus(60000)}**.

Here we have minus 1 minutes milliseconds("60000") with current date time.

If both is equals then proceed that queue into **FetchHDFS** processor it will fetch that particular file in which previous minute file.

Please let me know if you face any issues.